# How to get Exception message thrown by one of the specflow scenario's [Given-when-then] methods

Tags: c#, exception, bdd, specflow

I am using specflow for automating my test. As expected, when any of the [Given-when-then] methods say do not find and element, they throw exception. I want to get the error message of this exception in [afterscenario] method called after each scenario. 
Is this possible?

for example below is the error message I need to catch

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `ScenarioContext.Current.TestError`. I tried looking through the SpecFlow documentation, but I think I found this property by just drilling down into the `ScenarioContext.Current` property using Intellisense in Visual Studio.

```
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace Your.Project
{
    [Binding]
    public class CommonHooks
    {
        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            Exception lastError = ScenarioContext.Current.TestError;

            if (lastError != null)
            {
                if (lastError is OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException)
                {
                    // Test failure cause by not finding an element on the page
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid exceptions when running tests in a multi-threaded context when accessing `ScenarioContext.Current`, you can utilize the build-in dependency injection framework to pass the current context in as a constructor argument to your `CommonHooks` class:

```
[Binding]
public class CommonHooks
{
    public CommonHooks(ScenarioContext currentScenario)
    {
        this.currentScenario = currentScenario;
    }

    private ScenarioContext currentScenario;

    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterScenario()
    {
        Exception lastError = currentScenario.TestError;

        if (lastError != null)
        {
            if (lastError is OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException)
            {
                // Test failure cause by not finding an element on the page
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Grey, that worked like a charm...! :) ScenarioContext.Current.TestError is what I needed!

Comment: Is there a way to capture step binding errors (no matching, or multiple matching) with it?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest another variation that takes into account that the ScenarioContext.Current is obsolete.

Here is a Hooks class

```
public class Hooks
{
    [BeforeScenario]
    public void CreateWebDriver(ScenarioContext context)
    {
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        context["WebDriver"] = driver;
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterScenario(ScenarioContext context)
    {
        var driver = context["WebDriver"] as IWebDriver;            

        if (context.TestError != null)
        {
            //Do something();
        }
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```